# Can't boot ISO to my laptop in UNetbootin (Xubuntu 12.04 & Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, xubuntu, unetbootin

I was trying to install Linux Mint (and a few other OS's) through UNetbootin.  The ISO's burned alright, but when I tried to boot them up, I got the message: "Non-system boot disk.
Press any key to reboot."  I can't figure this out, so please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

UNetbootin Is A little complex. Maybe UNetbootin Didnt Create A boot file or something. I Recommend You Simply Use The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator if your Using A Usb.

If your Using A DVD/CD FOllow Here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu

If you Want To Use A USB Key Instead (Strongly Recommend it) Follow Here:http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Enjoy!

Comment: Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator doesn't work since somewhere around 12.04. Whoever maintains that software needs to fix a lot of bugs.